# Recommended Install Path for Intel Coffee Lake CPU?

Tags: system-installation, cpu

I'm planning on building a new Coffee Lake/8th gen based PC (i7-8700k), which is only supported in kernel version 4.13+. I'm fairly new to Elementary, but am loving it so far and I'd like to make it my daily driver. On my current build, it looks like the current kernel is 4.10.

Worst case I assume I could pull down a backport kernel from the ubuntu PPAs if I can even get the installer to load. Any other recommendations for how to approach this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update - I finally built this machine and got it all working.  The 0.4.1 installer loaded and worked just fine.  After setup, I installed the most recent stable kernel - 4.14.5 as of this answer.  This kernel includes support for coffee lake but you have to enable video drivers (I'm using onboard graphics) via the kernel flag: i915.alpha_support=1

It works without this, but you'll get some screen tear.  It sounds like 4.15 will fully support 8th gen Intel CPUs when it's released.  In any case, all is well.  For reference, my system is as follows:

- i7-8700k
- ASRock z370-itx
- 16GB Crucial Ballistix DDR4 3000 RAM
- Samsung 960 EVO SSD

Wireless, LAN, Audio, Bluetooth all work without a hitch.

Comment: Good to hear! Could you please mark the answer I gave as answered so others know to use the method?

Answer (score 1):

You could install Ukuu which makes it easy to install kernels, including 4.13, and roll back if the kernel causes issues. Check the link below on how to use it.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion!  I upvoted you but apparently it doesn't count because my account is new.